# NESTJS Validation Pipe and CustomValidatorDecorator with Service Layer

Tags: typescript, nestjs

Hello i am recently new on NESTJS and i need help to solve this problem. the problem consist that i need on the validation pipe to have access to the token of the request to call antoher api ( with the same token ) and using the HttpModule to check if the id sent was valid or not.

Validation Pipe ( Sample from nestjs docs):

```
@Injectable()
export class ValidationPipe implements PipeTransform<any> {
  async transform(value, { metatype }: ArgumentMetadata) {
    if (!metatype || !this.toValidate(metatype)) {
      return value;
    }
    const object = plainToClass(metatype, value);
    const errors = await validate(object);
    if (errors.length > 0) {
      throw new BadRequestException('Validation failed');
    }
    return value;
  }

  private toValidate(metatype): boolean {
    const types = [String, Boolean, Number, Array, Object];
    return !types.find((type) => metatype === type);
  }
}
```

Custom Validator :

```
import { registerDecorator, ValidationOptions, ValidationArguments } from 'class-validator';

export function IsLanguageValid(property: string, validationOptions?: ValidationOptions) {
  return function(object: Object, propertyName: string) {
    registerDecorator({
      name: 'isLanguageValid',
      target: object.constructor,
      propertyName: propertyName,
      constraints: [property],
      options: validationOptions,
      validator: {
        validate(value: any, args: ValidationArguments) {
          const [relatedPropertyName] = args.constraints;
          const relatedValue = (args.object as any)[relatedPropertyName];

          // WHERE HOW CAN I ACCESS TO A SERVICE AND TOKEN OF THE REQUEST
          this.httpModule.get('url to other api', { headers: { authrorization : TOKEN }})
        },
      },
    });
  };
}
```

What is the propose of that, on the DTO i put the decorators for validation and then he calls the api automatically to check the language_id exist or not.

```
  @ApiModelProperty()
  @IsLanguageValid({}, { message: 'the language id sent is not valid'})
  @IsNumber({}, { message: 'the id should be a number' })
  language_id: number;
```